# Background image isn't displaying full resolution

Tags: html, css

I have a background image that's about 1200 (w) x 800 (h) but i just want to use the whole 100% resolution for it. I have a button inside this div container but it's not displaying correctly. The background image won't expand to it's full resolution. It seems like it's only showing enough to allow the button to show.

```css
.endFoot {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/900x900');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.customButton {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 41%;
  padding: 25px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointed;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #AB0002;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="endFoot">
  <a href="link.html"><button class="customButton">TEXT</button></a>
</div>
```

here's a little picture demonstrating what's going wrong vs what i want:

[image: wrongvsright]

Comment: set  .endFoot    position:absolute

Comment: If you want to read more about background-image cover, this tutorial is very complete:  [Perfect Full Background Images](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with background image not expanding. Your div is simply not tall enough to show more of the image. Going off of your diagram, you want to add some padding to `.endFoot`.

`background-size: cover;` is a good choice, but you may also want to consider centering the position with `background-position: 50% 50%;`.

```css
.endFoot {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/900x900');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 400px 0 0 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.customButton {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 41%;
  padding: 25px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointed;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #AB0002;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="endFoot">
  <a href="link.html"><button class="customButton">TEXT</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: this is what i needed! i have 2 questions for you - if i resize the page, the background image doesn't resize with it, is there a way to fix that? Also, is it necessarily bad in a 'web responsive' sense to put a huge padding (900px) on this in order achieve the look i was going for?

Comment: Hmm, when I resize the window everything scales.Yes, a huge padding could be a less than good practice but I really don't know what you're trying to achieve here.To me, this feels like you should probably be setting the background image on `body` element.

Comment: The entire page has 4 sections in it and only the last one one uses the background image. It looks like if i do background-size: contain then it resizes but it leaves white spaces to keep the image in tact. Also tried background-size: 100% 100% which works but then it looks skewed. So im thinking maybe the image is just too big to resize down?

Comment: Yeah, don't do that with background sizing if you want to preserve proportions. I think I'd need to see a full example to help you any further. You may want to create a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the endFoot div to have the same height as the background, just set the height to 800px, because 100% doesn't change anything in this case.
Also set the endFoot position to relative in order to put the botton to the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve full screen background try :

```
.endFoot {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

For browser support informations of vh and vw units check : https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 0):

Just add **text-align:center** to **.endFoot** class to make center button and  add some **margin** to **.customButton** class for leave some space to bottom.

```css
.endFoot {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/900x900');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 400px 0 0 0px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customButton {
  padding: 25px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointed;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #AB0002;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="endFoot">
  <a href="link.html"><button class="customButton">TEXT</button></a>
</div>
```